# Feeding celery queue with it's own result

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selenium, celery

I'm coding a crawler for my SPA application. Since it's a SPA I can't use wget/curl or any other non-browser based solution for crawling, because I need a browser in order to run the javascript in my SPA.

I coded this using python and selenium. It will start at the homepage, scan for all `href` elements, save them in a `set`, discard the ones that I have already visited (`visited` as in `opened with selenium and collected all the href elements`), and take the next URL from the set and visit it. Then it will repeat the process over and over until it has visited all links.

The code looks like this:

```
def main():

    ...

    # Here we will be saving all the links that we can find in the DOM of
    # each visited URL
    collected = set()
    collected.add(crawler.start_url)

    # Here we will be saving all the URLs that we have already visited
    visited = set()

    base_netloc = urlparse(crawler.start_url).netloc

    while len(collected):
        url = collected.pop()

        urls = self.collect_urls(url)
        urls = [x for x in urls if x not in visited and urlparse(x).netloc == base_netloc]

        collected = collected.union(urls)
        visited.add(url)

    crawler.links = list(visited)
    crawler.save()

def collect_urls(self, url):
    browser = Browser()
    browser.fetch(url)

    urls = set()
    elements = browser.get_xpath_elements("//a[@href]")
    for element in elements:
        link = browser.get_element_attribute(element, "href")

        if link != url:
            urls.add(link)

    browser.stop()
    return urls
```

I want to make each call to `collect_urls` a Celery task, so it can retry if it fails, and also to make the entire thing faster (using several workers). The problem is that `collect_urls` is called from inside the `while`, which depends on the `collected` set, which is filled by the results of `collect_urls`.

I know I can call a Celery task with `delay()` and wait for the result with `get()`, so my code would then look like this:

```
    while len(collected):
        url = collected.pop()

        task = self.collect_urls.delay(url)
        urls = task.get(timeout=30)
```

That will convert my calls to `collect_urls` into Celery tasks, and it will allow me to retry if something fails, but I still won't be able to use more than one worker, as I need to wait for the result of `delay()`.

How can I refactor my code in such a way that it would allow me to use several workers for `collect_urls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, if you want this to be distributed for purposes of speed, you have to make the set of already visited websites into a cross-process-safe structure.  You could do this, for example, by storing it as a set in redis or in a database table.  Once you do that, you can update your code to do the following:

```
# kick off initial set of tasks:
result_id = uuid.uuid4()
for x in collected:
    task = self.collect_urls.delay(x, result_id)
return result_id
```

You can use that result_id to periodically check to the set of visited urls.  Once that set has had the same length for `n` number of calls, you deem that it is done.

In the collect_urls function, you essentially do:

```
def collect_urls(self, url, result_id):
    # for example, you can use redis smember to check if the 
    # set at result_id contains url
    if url has been visited:
        return
    # you can do this in redis using sadd
    add url to the set of visited
    # collect urls as before
    ...
    # but instead of returning the urls, you kick off new tasks
    for x in urls:
        collect_urls.delay(x, result_id)
```

If you used redis, all of the collected / visited urls would be contained in the redis key identified by result_id.  You don't have to use redis, you can just as easily do this with rows in a database which have result_id as one column, and the url in another.

Comment: I like the idea! But I think there is another problem with this approach. Several workers might be working on the same URL, as there is no locking. I mean, the check `if url has been visited` might return `false` for one worker, so that worker will start collecting URLs from that URL, but exactly after that check is done, another worker could do `add url to the set of visited`, because that second worker just finished collecting the URLs of that URL. Is there a way I can avoid/fix that?

Comment: In order to do that, you'd have to do a secondary lock.  In redis, I'd use something like setnx.  So if setnx "result_id:url" == my unique ID, then I can work on the URL.  Otherwise, return early.